# Set default sort on column in php from a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, html-table

I'm pulling some data from database, it's a private site so im not too worried about using mysql right now although I do understand I should be using PDO, just haven't made the switch yet:

```
<table id="table" border="1" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">         
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
       <span class="th">
           <span class="arrow"></span>
           <span class="icon"></span>
           <span class="title">Exception ID</span>
       </span>
</th>
<th>
       <span class="th">
           <span class="arrow"></span>
           <span class="icon"></span>
           <span class="title">Exception</span>
       </span>
</th>
<th>
       <span class="th">
           <span class="arrow"></span>
           <span class="icon"></span>
           <span class="title">First 250 chars of code</span>
       </span>
</th>
<th>
       <span class="th">
           <span class="arrow"></span>
           <span class="icon"></span>
           <span class="title"># of exceptions</span>
       </span>
</th>
<th>
       <span class="th">
           <span class="arrow"></span>
           <span class="icon"></span>
           <span class="title">Bug #</span>
       </span>
</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>

    <?php
//Need to find the total rows in the snippets_link_email_id because well need to show the last x records, so we get total number or rows and then minus the total RECORDS to only select the last x
$total_snippet_check = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(email_id) as num_rows FROM snippets_link_email_id");
$row = mysql_fetch_object($total_snippet_check);
$total_rows = $row->num_rows;


//finding out how many exceptions there was in the last 24 hours from a table that records total exceptions every hour
$how_many_recent_crashes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM crash_log_entries ORDER BY crash_id DESC LIMIT 24");
    while ($row_recent_crashes = mysql_fetch_array($how_many_recent_crashes))
    {
        $crash_processed = $row_recent_crashes['crash_processed'];
        $crash_processed_total += $crash_processed;
    }

$which_records = $total_rows - $crash_processed_total;


    //need info on that snippet
$feedback_query_first = 
    "SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS tot_snippets
    FROM snippets 
    LEFT JOIN snippets_link_email_id
    ON (snippets.snippet_id = snippets_link_email_id.snippet_id)
    WHERE snippets_link_email_id.email_id > $which_records
    GROUP BY snippets.snippet_id
    ORDER BY tot_snippets asc";

$result1 = mysql_query($feedback_query_first);

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
        {   
        $i = $row1['snippet_id'];
        //Need to find the total snippets for the current snippet
        $feedback_query = mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM snippets 
        LEFT JOIN snippets_link_email_id
        ON snippets.snippet_id = snippets_link_email_id.snippet_id 
        WHERE snippets_link_email_id.snippet_id = $i 
        AND snippets_link_email_id.email_id > $which_records");
        $tot_snippets = mysql_num_rows($feedback_query);

        $snippet_text_pre = $row1['snippet_text'];
        $snippet_text_pre1 = htmlspecialchars($snippet_text_pre);
        $snippet_text = str_replace("&lt;br /&gt;", "<br />",$snippet_text_pre1);
        $snippet_text =  substr($snippet_text,0,250);

        $comment = $row1['comment'];
        $comment_short = substr($comment, 0, 35);
        $note_length = strlen($comment);
        $snippet_id = $row1['snippet_id'];
        $email_id = $row1['email_id'];


        $query_exceptions = "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email_id = $email_id ORDER BY email_id DESC";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query_exceptions);

        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
        {
        $actual_exception = $row2['actual_exception'];  
        }

            echo '<tr><td>'.$snippet_id.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $actual_exception.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $snippet_text.'....</td>';
            echo '<td>'. $tot_snippets.'</td>';
            $tot_tot += $tot_snippets;
            echo '<td>'. $comment . '</td></tr>';

        }   


echo "</tbody></table>"; 

echo "the total exceptions for this time period is: " . $tot_tot . "<br />";    
?>
```

Ok hopefully that is ok, I filtered out everything irrelevant so hopefully that code makes some sense. Now is there a way to sort by `$tot_snippets` by default when the page loads without using a full jquery sorting solution as I only want to sort this by this column always as I don't need to update it? I don't think I can sort this using `orderby` since the value of `tot_snippets` is not a column value but all the solutions I seem to find have a full blown sorting solution and most involve Jquery, if Jquery is the best option so be it but I thought there might be an easier way?

//Edit
 I updated the code and added basically the whole code, I realize my code is messy, I'm self taught and just learned enough to do what I need to do. I'm sure it could be altered to be a lot more compact but my main issue is even with one of the previous solutions it still doesn't sort by the # of exceptions column, I'm guessing the solutions giving were good by my leaving out some of the other code meant it didn't work so I decided to include the whole code this time. I originally left it out to make it less complicated but I now realize that probably was counter productive.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually combine these two queries:

```
SELECT snippets.snippet_id,COUNT(snippets_link_email_id.id) FROM snippets 
LEFT JOIN snippets_link_email_id ON snippets.snippet_id = snippets_link_email_id.snippet_id 
WHERE snippets_link_email_id.snippet_id = $i 
AND snippets_link_email_id.email_id > $which_records
GROUP BY snippets.snippet_id
```

Which means you only have to do one query rather than (numsnippets + 1) queries. This also allows ordering by the count by adding:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(snippets_link_email_id.id)
```

To the end of the query.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i updated my code as your solution didnt work for me and i suspect it was because i left out important parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can skip the first query. and get the distinct id's in the second query
using a group by snippet_id.
Then you can add a count to the query (i used the alias tot_snippets)
and order by the alias tot_snippets.
Then you get a query like this

`select 
*, count(*) as tot_snippets
 from snippets
 left join snippets_link_email_id on(snippets.snippet_id = snippets_link_email_id.snippet_id)
 where snippets_link_email_id.email_id > $which_records
 group by snippets.snippet_id
 order by tot_snippets asc`

To make your query more readable use aliases on the tables and name the column snippet_id in table snippets just id this makes it easier to understand your query

Comment: thanks, i wasnt 100% sure how to apply this but i updated my code and maybe it makes more sense now

Comment: maybe i wasnt clear but don't do a mysql_num_rows on the query i provide you will get a row vor every snippet_id with a column tot_snippets in it can you show your code with the query i provided implemented, that makes it more clear to me